# Increase row number every time a flag changes

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g

I have gone through a similar post in Stack overflow...
but my query is :

If my table generates a flag in run time execution,then how can I increase Grp_number(generate run time) every time my flag changes.

my Oracle query:

```
Select emp_id,
Case when MOD(rownum/3)=1 and rownum>1 then 'Y' else 'N' as flag
from Transaction_table
```

Desired o/p Data format:

```
emp_id    Flag    GRP_number
  1        N          1
  2        N          1
  3        N          1
  4        Y          2
  5        N          2
  6        N          2
  7        Y          3
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563581/increment-row-number-when-value-of-field-changes-in-oracle) @sudhir

Comment: Hi Skizo,  I have gone through that before. But since i am generating my flag run time , i am unable to use that flag column for further calculation of grp_number in the query.

Comment: Hi Skizo,  I have gone through that before. But since i am generating my flag run time , i am unable to use that flag column for further calculation of grp_number in the query.   

Below is the query that i have tried for but getting error for INVALID IDENTIFIER 'flag': 


select emp_id, flag, sum(gap) over (partition by emp_id order by emp_id) GRP_number from
(
select  emp_id , 
Case when MOD(rownum,30)=1 and rownum>1 then 'N' else 'Y' end as flag, 
case when flag= lag(flag) over (partition by emp_id order by emp_id) then 0 else 1 end gap
  from TRANSACTION_table
)

 Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: You cannot reference a column in another column in the same select list. You need to use `sub query` to avoid `INVALID IDENTIFIER` error. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference a column in another column in the same select list. You need to use **sub query** to avoid **INVALID IDENTIFIER** error.

Do it like -

```
WITH DATA AS(
SELECT emp_id,
    CASE
      WHEN MOD(rownum/3)=1
      AND rownum        >1
      THEN 'Y'
      ELSE 'N' AS flag
      FROM Transaction_table
  )
  SELECT emp_id, flag, SUM(gap) over (PARTITION BY person
                                            ORDER BY DAY) grp
     FROM(
          SELECT emp_id, flag,
                  CASE WHEN flag = lag(flag) over (PARTITION BY person
                                                   ORDER BY DAY)
                       THEN 0
                       ELSE 1
                  END gap
             FROM DATA)
```

Comment: Thanks Lalit... But since i am assigning flag on rownum the out put is getting varied since all the time the output doesn't come in same order. Is there any way i can assign the flag on any other basis other than rownum for 30 records each.

I am not getting the desired output as expected.

Comment: You could first ORDER BY in a subquery and then use rownum outside. Just like top-n rows. Something like, `select * from(select emp_id, rownum rn from table order by emp_id)` This query will give you ordered rows.